# How to use built-in table functions with table input, as with the user-definedtable-functions in Snowflake, without error invalid identifier?

Tags: sql, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I try to pass the value to a built-in function tag_references it fails with `invalid identifier C1`.

```
SELECT  C1.TABLE_CATALOG , 
        C1.TABLE_SCHEMA ,
        C1.TABLE_NAME , 
        C1.COLUMN_NAME
FROM DEMO_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C1  
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA !='INFORMATION_SCHEMA' 
AND (select count(*) 
     from table(demo_db.information_schema.tag_references(
                C1.TABLE_NAME || '.' || C1.COLUMN_NAME, 'COLUMN')
               ) 
     where tag_name in ('PII_CARD','PII_EMAIL')
    ) < 1;
```

I want to select only those for which there is no tag applied in PII_EMAIL OR PII_CARD.

Comment: Either use dynamic SQL or  SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TAG_REFERENCES views: [Snowflake query for a specific tag value against an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75879774/5070879)

Comment: Due to latency issues I can't use SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TAG_REFERENCES views.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.